# Alternate account to remind askers to accept answers when I am one of the answerers

Tags: discussion, etiquette, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

There are many instances when a question receives satisfactory answers yet none of them is accepted. Specifically, in situations when the asker has explicitly commented below useful answers that their problems were resolved or made no comment anywhere at all, and if I am not one of the answerers, I tend to leave this message:

> If you are satisfied with any of the answers below, consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark button next to the answer. Doing so will reward reputation points to you and the answerer for taking the time out to help you. If you are not satisfied, please feel free to comment on their answers and ask for clarification.

However, when I am one of the $(\ge2)$ answerers of such a question, it seems inappropriate to post this message as the asker may be obliged to accept my answer. Thus my questions are:

$(1)$ Is it against rules to open an alternate account solely for gently reminding askers to accept useful answers in such situations, without obliging them to accept my answer? This throw-away account would not be used for any other purpose, flouting rules or abuse. Would this be considered an "interaction" with my main account? Related: [I have 7 accounts is this ok](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8598/i-have-7-accounts-is-this-ok).

$(2)$ Notwithstanding the rules, will it be perceived as offensive by the community?

$(3)$ Is it not worth the effort? I guess *some* old users would come to associate the alternate with my main account due to its specific behaviour over time, denting its utility. But the primary aim is to conceal my identity generally from new and relatively low reputation askers.

$(4)$ If the answer to any question above is "YES", is there a better alternative to achieve what I want? I am not looking for feature-suggestions, but only what can be done using the current functionality.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I personally think this is a great use of a second account, though I won't bother setting one up :)

Comment: I think it is a bad idea.  It may not be a literal violation of the rules, but it violates the spirit of the rules.  You propose to create the second account for a specific routine of reminding users to accept Answers when you are one of the potential beneficiaries.  Concealing your potential interest in the suggested acceptance doesn't mitigate the conflict.

Comment: I have also left messages like yours, Shubham, including times when one of the answers was mine, and I've never felt that I was putting any pressure on the user to accept my answer over one of the others. As long as I am being above board by having my name on both comment and answer, and as long as I don't word my comment to favor any one answer, I reckon I'm OK.

Comment: FYR: a [comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/629362) for the same suggestion.

Comment: Hmm. OK I guess I am convinced by hardmath. But still, we ideally want to see the most helpful answers Accepted by OPs. In so far as OP does not try to suggest their own answer is better in any way, I don't see it as very different than a random person politely reminding the asker to do what they are already expected to do.

Comment: I know you're not looking for feature-suggestions, but perhaps they should be considered.  What if questions with multiple significantly upvoted answers were to occasionally generate a comment or message to the asker reminding about how to accept an answer?  This of course is not specific to this site.

Comment: Aacepting an answer is rewarded with 2 rep points. Apart from that there are many comments like the one you or Gerry Myerson mention to encourage this behavior. But I don't think we need to go to that extent to create a new account. Some of my answers have been accepted after years of posting so I really don't worry too much on that front.

Answer (score 15):

You can have as many accounts as you'd like. But they must act as one. In particular, what you wouldn't do with one account, you shouldn't do with the other.

It's not that it's against the rules as much as it is a type of self promotion that is not great.

So overall, please don't do that.

Comment: moderator Karagila giving good advice ( : particularly  "So overall, _please don't do that._" And there should be a kind of note saying what your saying when about to create a second account.

Comment: Hi Asaf, thanks for your response. I understand that what I mentioned is not necessarily against the rules but is not generally well received by the community. What is the alternative? Do you think it is okay to remind the asker using my main account, as some other users have pointed out?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: Easy, just don't worry about it.

Comment: Almost a month later and another user asked about something like this.. I've linked them to your answer.