# Is it ok to use an alternate account for meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, multiple-accounts

I don't like to use my main account for meta because I find that some people like to downvote my stuff (imho somewhat randomly) after I get into some sort of argument on the site.

I also don't like the drama that comes with many meta posts. For example, when you post in undeletion request many times the entire "situation" gets sort of pathetic. It would be cool if all that drama wasn't one click away from my math profile.

In any case, is it ok to use a different account for meta? Obviously doing things like multiple voting or voting on ones own post is wrong. Or acting in ways that would be wrong if it was my main account is also clearly not ok, this includes things like using the alternate account to circunvent suspensions, it also includes going against the rules in the requests for unclosure and undeletion. (although those rules seemed to be added by a moderator when we move from version $2$ to version $3$ , but w/e) .

Comment: If you don't like drama on the site, why do you get into some sort of argument(s)?

Comment: It happens, I'm sure it has happened to a lot of people who don't like drama. Although unfortunately I don't fully understand the phenomenon.

Comment: The only issue I'm concerned about is:  Mods need to know, in the even of the need for a suspension, that both usernames belong to the same account.  If a user is suspended for any reason, even if only for a day, their account becomes inactive/inoperable on both meta and main.  If suspended, say from a math.se moderator, under your main username, if you remained active on meta, that could be deemed "trying to circumvent a suspension.  plus, to have two users names, one for each main and meta, you'd have to create both on main.  So the risk of the accounts interacting, is far greater.

Comment: In the end, this question would best be answered by a moderator here.  Better yet, you should ask this question on [Meta.SE], which has a wealth of knowledge regarding how this network operates, common questions that come up often, etc.

Comment: The bottom line, it could work, but you'd have to discipline yourself to never interact (upvote, edit, vote to reopen, aske more questions that allotted to one account, etc., one account with the other, ever, and also you'd need to refrain from using both accounts if either account were suspended, or given a question ban or answer ban.

Comment: I don't like very much the idea of having an extra account to mess around without consequences on your "main" account. Either you are contributing peacefully on both math & meta, and you have nothing to fear, either you plan to argue, and such an attitude makes me uncomfortable. And you seem to be suggesting the latter.

Comment: Well, if you got to any of the multiple threads requesting undeletion and unclosure you will see that the place is pretty unpleasant @Jean-ClaudeArbaut In fact, I could reserve my account for only posting there, and even then, not posting on anything that has either my answers or my questions.

Comment: Related https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33585/

Comment: @Jean, a case could be made that nothing one does on meta should have any consequences on main (provided one doesn't do something utterly shocking on meta). As for planning to argue, it is certainly possible to find oneself in the middle of an argument, without ever having intended to take part in one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Agreed. But I have only had to suffer vengeful downvotes once or twice, and either it's massive and automatically reverted, or it's limited and of no consequence. One should not pay to much attention to this. So I definitely think it's not worth having to hide behind a second anonymous account. But it's not forbidden, and it's his decision. I think it's really only useful if one gets blocked for misbehavior, to circumvent the suspension. And *that*, I think, is forbidden here.

Comment: When users post with requests to reopen or undelete a post,  we expect them to disclose any vested interest they have in it's undeletion/reopening.  If one is the author of the question, or an answerer of the question, we expect a user to disclose that information.  If you want to hide so no one can see you are the asker or answerer of a question you post about here, that is dishonest.

Comment: funnily enough I already got a revenge downvote on my only question :/

Comment: Oh and a question to one of my answers also got deleted, fabulous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic rules are:

- One can have more than one account.
- One must not do anything that one could not do with one account.

This means it is not forbidden to engage in meta with a "second" account, especially not if one does not with the main one.

I personally would advice against it except in special circumstances. Something I would find alright as a use-case is to ask about something that is linked to ones main account, but one does not want to draw attention to it or disclose it. More broadly, I'd see little issue for most things that are actual support questions.

However, if somebody wants to engage in discussion it becomes tricky. It tends to cause friction if there are accounts that appear new or marginal, but the poster clearly seems well versed on the site. It could lead to speculations who it might be.  And so on. We actually had such cases in the past. It is not a great situation.

Comment: Great, thank you very much.